# Is it the situation solved if I upgrade my firebase plan?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

After I sent the message, I found error logs in firebase functions tab.

[image]

Therefore I don't received push message.

I don't know reason why appears this situation. Do I have to change my firebase plan from spark to blaze? Is the Firebase policy changed?

Comment: It looks like you have an error in the code of your function. It is unlikely that this has anything to do with being on the free plan. Please update your question to include the [minimum code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: From a quick scan it seems like your code is still using the beta syntax. You will need to upgrade it to v1.0, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: What can I do for restransmiting failed message from my web / app server (java) to FCM Server? I would like to send 1000 messages and retransmit only those that failed. Is there any way? Are there any methods to identify each failed message, such as a unique message ID? As you can see, there is no identifiable message ID. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737476/what-can-i-do-for-restransmiting-failed-message-from-my-web-app-server-java