# What can I do for restransmiting failed message from my web / app server (java) to FCM Server

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, httpurlconnection

I would like to send 1000 messages and retransmit only those that failed. Is there any way?

Are there any methods to identify each failed message, such as a unique message ID?

As you can see, there is no identifiable message ID.

Is actually possible that only one message should be resent as in this case?
Should I resend only this message or all the bulk?

Should I use Exponential Backoff? Then, Where can I find example source?

[image]